# What does 'square' inside checkbox mean for 'optimize code' in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

After adding new build configuration, the new configuration has 'optimize code' checkbox value set like this:
[image]

This 'square' is usually used to represent, that the option is enabled for some of the child elements, or that configuration is [inherited](https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/99977). What does it mean in this case? Are the optimizations turned on, or off? I'd assume, they are on, but when I explicitly untick and tick again, the section is added to csproj:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='test3|AnyCPU'">
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**[EDIT]** The question ["Optimize code" checkbox in Visual Studio. What exactly does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314433/the-optimize-code-checkbox-in-visual-studio-what-exactly-does-it-do) does not in any way answers what does this specific 'in beetween' state mean.

**[EDIT2]** It is clear for me, what the below means, because all configurations are selected:

[image]

The question is, why it's the case for a single new configuration. Is it because Platform active is set to 'Any CPU'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The "Optimize code" checkbox in Visual Studio. What exactly does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314433/the-optimize-code-checkbox-in-visual-studio-what-exactly-does-it-do)

Comment: It means some configs have it on and some off. Debug will have it disabled and release enabled. Change the active configuration above and it will chamr to unchecked/full checked.

Comment: What language and project type is this for? That would help narrow down the hundreds of different build configurations visual studio supports.

Comment: @Casey Sorry I did not added the tags. This is for c# in .NET Standard 2.0

Comment: @DaveShaw You mean some platform configurations have it on and some off? Changing active configuration does not change it's state. It's added, when you add new build configuration, it's not for Debug or Release

Comment: The checkbox state means "unspecified".  Looks like a bug to me.  When you add a new configuration then you get to pick the configuration whose settings you want to copy from.  Usually Debug.  What it is *supposed* to do is copy this setting as well, but apparently it doesn't.  The workaround is an easy one.