# C# compiler - what optimizations are performed with the 'optimize code' flag turned on?

Tags: c#, optimization, compiler-construction

I'm planning on gaining some insights into inheritance usage for .NET systems written in C#. I want to analyse Intermediate Language code instead of C# code to make it possible to also look at compiled code. Is there any information available on which optimizations the C# compiler may do when the optimize code flag is enabled?

I'm analysing call behavior related to inheritance graphs (e.g. using polymorphism, reuse methods from base class, etc).

Most questions and resources on the internet say 'minor optimizations' and other vague things. I need to specifically know the changes in semantics that might occur when compiling for release mode. I am not interested in the performance of code.

For example, Scott Hanselman posts in [his blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReleaseISNOTDebug64bitOptimizationsAndCMethodInliningInReleaseBuildCallStacks.aspx) that method inlining will occur in release mode. But that is just one example. This means that [What is /optimize C# compiler key intended for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969183/what-is-optimize-c-sharp-compiler-key-intended-for) **does not** answer my question.

Comment: Might be useful to elaborate on why you're interested in this, for example, are you concerned about performance?

Comment: Does this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969183/what-is-optimize-c-sharp-compiler-key-intended-for

Comment: @Jim, yes thank you, I was aware of that one. But I wonder if there is a more detailed source.

Answer (score 2):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do.aspx

Eric Lippert (a former principal developer on the C# compiler team) answered this on his blog. A few of the remarks:

- Eliminate dead code (branches which are never reached, checks that always return true,...)
- nullcheck optimization.
- removal of intermittent calls (`A(B(C(D)))` is rewritten as `A(D)`);
- double return calls.

The entire blog has many more examples and I urge you to read it if you want to know about this.